# Дана уже известная дата,найти по ней нужные записи с помощью условного оператора

Tags: python

Ситуация следующая
Известны даты,по которым нужно найти определённые записи

По заданию нужен условный оператор.

Есть 2 атрибута даты - `datetakeorder, dateorder`

**Что я хотел представить под кодом ниже?**

При проходе по всей коллекции записей `bookorders` используется условный оператор с уже известной датой,и на основе этого условия выводить записи на экран.

```
 def showhum(self):
        for bookorder in bookorders:
              if self.datetakeorder=='15.09.1990':                      
                 print(self.surn)

  def quantman(self):
        counthum=0
        for bookorder in bookorders:
              if self.dateorder=='25.04.1990':
                    counthum+=1
        print("Количество людей,которые заказали книгу 25.04.1990 - ",counthum)
```

Компилятор сразу сообщает `Syntax Error`.
Как можно ещё решить данную проблему?

Пробовал преобразования в str,задавал константно но результатов это не дало.
Но не рассматривал ещё регулярные выражения и парсинг.

Здесь 2 уже известные даты, и стоит ли парсить или задавать регулярное выражение,не понимаю..

Comment: Табуляции у вас криво стоят, а в остальном не вижу проблем.

Comment: Покажите ошибку целиком, она может быть и "наведённая" - вызванная предыдущим кодом

Comment: Напишите целиком сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Пользователь @CrazyElf подсказал правильно, это было предыдущим кодом.
Когда я дату стал вводить в строковом варианте `str`,а не в формате `datetime`то всё заработало.